Auto IK stopped working completely
Version: 4.2
Without seemingly anything triggering this, Auto IK just stopped working completely, choosing any bone, and trying to use autoIK, just turns the bone that's selected orange, and refuse to do anything besides rotating it, using pose mirror and moving anything doesn't reset it at all, like with the problem that breaks it that way.

